# Neo4j browser in an iframe - how to set frame-ancestors security policy

Tags: iframe, neo4j

With Neo4j community version 3.1.1, I successfully embedded the Neo4j browser in an iframe in a web application I created.  With version 3.2.0, the following error occurs when trying to view the browser through an iframe:

> Refused to display 'http://xxxxxx:7474/browser/' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".

Is there a way to configure the Neo4j server to set Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' or to the specific address where I am running Neo4j?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is due to the following headers (as for Neo4J 3.2.1):

- Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'
- X-Frame-Options: DENY

Those headers are hardly enforced by the `org.neo4j.server.web.StaticContentFilter` that is statically loaded by `org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty9WebServer.loadStaticContent(SessionManager, String)`

So for now, it seems there is no option or parameter that can be used to by-pass this security.

Any update is welcome !